# Issue with storing object in Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

Here is the sample output for my code, a simple chat program:

```
John says: Hello there!
Marsha says: Hi there!
John says:  First sentence.
Marsha says:  Second Sentence.
```

In the textbox control, it appears like above.  However, in the dictionary used to store the conversation, it will go like this:

```
John says: First sentence.
Marsha says: Hi there!
John says: First sentence.
Marsha says: Second sentence.
```

I've gone over my code several times... for the life of me, I cannot tell exactly where I'm possible going wrong on this.

I've traced the problem to the sendmsgbutton method, presented here:

```
Private Sub sendMsgButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles sendMsgButton.Click
    If rtnConnectStatus(t) = False Then
        RaiseEvent statusCheck("Not Connected" + ControlChars.CrLf)
    Else
        Dim completeMsg As String
        msg.Name = nameText.Text
        msg.Message = msgTxt.Text
        completeMsg = msg.ToString
        msgRecorded.Text &= completeMsg
        RaiseEvent statusCheck("Message Sent." + ControlChars.CrLf)
        msgList.Add(msgListIndex, msg)
        'RaiseEvent debugBox(msg, msgListIndex)
        msgListIndex += 1
        RaiseEvent DataSend(completeMsg)
        msgTxt.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is the dictionary class that msgList inherits from:

```
Public Class MsgDictionary
     Inherits DictionaryBase

Public Property Item(ByVal key As Integer) As MsgObj
    Get
        Return CType(Dictionary(key), MsgObj)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal m As MsgObj)
        Dictionary(key) = m
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub Add(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal m As MsgObj)
    Dictionary.Add(index, m)
End Sub

End Class
```

My next testing is to see if it's *only* the message value or if the name value is also affected by this.

Thank you, in advance, for any help/advice you can give on this.

Edit: Just to clarify, the Name and string portion of each dictionary entry as properties of a single dictionary object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is clear: you are considering a dictionary performing one by one associations when the reality calls for a different thing. Your code associates "John says:" to "Hello there!" and then to "First sentence." (the value which you finally see). What you have to do is associating "John says:" with a list of actions.

If you want to rely on a dictionary, you should re-define it such that it can associate each key to a list of values, that is:

```
Dim newDic = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
```

and then you can populate it with the right information. Example:

```
Dim msgList As New List(Of String)
msgList.Add("Hello there!")
msgList.Add("First sentence.")
newDic.Add("John says:", msgList)
```

Logically, you have to adapt this code to what you really need (i.e., redefine your custom dictionary and the data types).

Comment: First, thank you for your reply.  I edited the original response, but I also wanted to check with you about this.  Each entry in the dictionary is meant to be a single Message Object with two variables (Name and Message) within each object.  Based on your response, it looks like this would still apply regardless, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Yes, no problem at all. If you have defined a specific type/class including two properties(Name and Message) you can create a list with it as with strings; and thus you will have a list of couples Name-Message. Just use the structure I proposed by replacing "string" with "MsgObj".

Comment: Final comment on how this was resolved, as this answer was helpful in finding the extra data.  (This is mostly for those that find this question.  I had discovered it was still going on, even when putting the data into an object.  However, I also had my "MsgObj" object as a _global variable_.  Since the dictionary was still referencing that variable, it was changing and duplicating itself in the dictionary.  So I moved it to a local variable in the send method instead.  After ensuring unique data, everything went exactly as it should.  Thanks again.